# split an array into different arrays based on their consecutive elements

Tags: c++

i have array like this.This array has 100 elements and I want to split this array into different arrays with 20 elements.

```
int main()
{
    int array[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        
    }

}
```

I want to split this array into different arrays with 20 elements each. The arrays will be as follows =

array0=[0.. to 20]

array1=[1.. to 21]

array2=[2.. to 22]
.

.

.

array80=[80..to 100]

How can I best solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your best effort at solving this yourself for others to comment on (see [mre]).  We don't write code for people here.

Comment: whats the point of such splitting ?

Comment: *How can I best solve this problem?* --  Do you really want to have a view of 20 consecutive elements, starting at element `n`, thus no need to create copies?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: First, create a  **baseline**, the simplest way that produces the correct answer, even if it is O(N^infinite). Then try to optimize.
For performance, I would create 5 arrays of the same size of the original as to cope with degenerated cases. Then run, filter and shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very vague, and I'm not sure what you want to do. If I base on the result you just want. this will be it.

I use Dynamic Array Allocation (2D array), to avoid declaring new int array too much.

*check the code below as reference:*

`arr[0]` base on you is the same as `array0=[0.. to 20]`

and

`arr[0][0]` is the same as `array0[0]`;

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        
        
        int array[100];
        
        // 0 - 19 means there is 20 int
        // base on your example it seems you want is 21 items in each array
        // just change the divide_by into 21 to achieve `0 to 20`
        int divide_by = 20; //  How many int in an (array of int)

        int arr_len = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)); 
        // you can just write 100 here but if you do not know what is the length of the array, this will adjust automatically
        
        int new_array_lenth = arr_len-divide_by;
        
        // 1 to 80 means 80 numbers
        // 0 to 80 means 81 numbers
        // that is why there is +1 in new_array_length 
        ++new_array_lenth;
        
        // base on your example of 0 to 80
        // array0=[0.. to 20]
        // array1=[1.. to 21]
        // array2=[2.. to 22]
        // array80=[80..to 100]
        // array0 to array80 means there is 81 (array of int)
        
        // list of int_array
        int** arr = new int*[new_array_lenth]; // length is 81
    
        // your code
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            array[i] = i; 
            // cout << i << endl; 
            // this will show 0 to 99
            // 1 to 99 means 99 numbers
            // 0 to 99 means there are 100 numbers
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < new_array_lenth; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[divide_by];
            for (int j = 0; j < divide_by; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = array[i + j];
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        
        cout << arr[0][0] << " - " << arr[0][divide_by - 1] << endl; // 0 - 19
        cout << arr[1][0] << " - " << arr[1][divide_by - 1] << endl; // 1 - 20
        cout << arr[2][0] << " - " << arr[2][divide_by - 1] << endl; // 2 - 21
    
        // just change the divide_by into 21 and the result will be 0 - 20, 1-21, 2,22

        return 0;
    }
```

copy paste this code to the compiler to see the result

Link: [compiler online](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/)

Comment: Why did you leave out the all important issue of deallocating the memory?  And to that, why not introduce the usage of `std::vector`, as that is the preferred method of creating dynamic arrays in modern C++.